# Aggregatin function doesn't work correct in join for some reasons

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, average, aggregate-functions

I got a problem with current joins. Aggregation function returns incorrect amount in it for some reasons. When I run following query, I get no rows in result:

```
 SELECT 
   CONCAT( pp.FirstName, ' ', pp.LastName) AS 'CustomerName', 
   ssoh.Status AS 'OrderStatus',
   FORMAT (ssoh.OrderDate, 'yyyy-dd-MM') AS OrderDate, ItemCount, AvgQty
 FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS ssoh
 JOIN Person.Person AS pp ON pp.BusinessEntityID = ssoh.CustomerID
 JOIN ( 
   SELECT SalesOrderID, SUM(ssod.OrderQty) AS ItemCount, AVG(ssod.OrderQty) AS AvgQty
   FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS ssod
   GROUP BY ssod.SalesOrderID
   HAVING SUM(ssod.OrderQty) > 300 
 ) AS ssod ON ssoh.SalesOrderID = ssod.SalesOrderID
 ORDER BY ssod.ItemCount DESC
```

When I run this query separately:

```
Select SUM(OrderQty), SalesOrderID
From Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Where SUM(OrderQty) > 300
Group BY SalesOrderID
Order by desc
go
```

I get some rows, that means my way of thinking is not wrong and I made a mistake in my script. Help me, please.

Comment: Interesting the `WHERE` clause with aggregate even works in second code block as it should be in `HAVING`! Please test **same** aggregate in both cases and please define *doesn't work* or *returns incorrect amount*. Is it double/triple by `SalesOrderID`?

Comment: TSQL error (assumed from `GO`): `An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

Comment: I ran second script SEPARATELY, to make sure that SUM(OrgerQty) grater than 300 exists indeed. I got like a dozen rows in the result. When I ran first script I did not get any values grater than 8 (I removed HAVING clause to see a result of SUM function).

Comment: See if converting Inner join to Left join can make any difference.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've tried this option already. It doesn't make any difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use having not where here:

```
Select SUM(OrderQty) as s, SalesOrderID
From Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Group BY SalesOrderID
HAVING SUM(OrderQty) > 300
Order by s desc
```

---

Edit to get order to work on SQL Server

```
SELECT x.s, x.salesorderid
FROM (
  Select SUM(OrderQty) as s, SalesOrderID
  From Sales.SalesOrderDetail
  Group BY SalesOrderID
  HAVING SUM(OrderQty) > 300
) x
Order by x.s desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It matches the last join of my script. It is not working correct with OrderQty (sum is not correct). After running the script I get 0 rows.(((   When I run the small script SEPARATELY, I get right sum.